# How to retrieve a single result from 2 entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
| Report1 | Report2   |
| ------  | --------  |
| sid     | sid       |
| name    | name      |
| salary  | department|
report1.sid == report2.sid
```

My goal is to view the result of 2 different entity data together. Both sid report will be same and unique to the user. The result I wanted to show would sid,name,salary,department. I am able to view them separately as I am using the findAll() however I wish to find all the data in a single findAll()
I have tried using join columns however it added another column to my database table.

```
Entity
Report1
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "REPORT1")
public class Report1 {
    @Id
    private String SID;
    private String NAME;
    private double AMOUNT;
}
-------------------------------
Report2
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "REPORT2")
public class Report2 {
    @Id
    private String SID;
    private String DEPARTMENT;
    private String NAME;
}
```

repo

```
public interface Report1Repository extends JpaRepository<Report1,Integer> {
}
public interface Report1Repository extends JpaRepository<Report2,Integer> {
}
```

Comment: You can create DTO to represents the combined data. and then you can modify your repositories to retrieve the combined data using a query.

Comment: is there other option other than creating a DTO ?

Comment: You can use Tuple interface too. Here is examples: 
https://www.javatpoint.com/java-tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use tuple and custom query like this example :
for your repository :

```
public interface Report1Repository extends JpaRepository<Report1,Integer> {
@Query(native=true, value='select r1.sid sid, r1.name name, r1.salary salary, r2.department department from report1 r1 left join report2 r2 on r1.sid = r2.sid')
List<ReportTuple> findAllReports();
}
```

and create a tuple interface like this :

```
public interface ReportTuple{
    
    Long getSid();
    String getName();
    String getDepartment();
    Long getSalary();
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Custom Class like DTO or VO to represent all the data and create custom query to which returns all the records and prepare DTO list accordingly